# How to get vscode automatically renaming a file on saving?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to have a vscode code/plugin to rename the file to the current epoch time every time that the respective file is saved ?

Comment: is that not what version control (like `git`) is invented for?

Comment: No @Luuk. I need that every time the developer using the vscode save a given file with the .myext extension , the current file automatically get renamed to the current time epoch. I need to enforce some filename pattern.

Comment: the extension in VSCODE with the name `Run On Save` seems to come close, but cannot save with current epoch time. (and documentation is .... )